# Missing photos from Micro SDXC card Nikon D600

Tags: nikon, sdcard

I have an A-DATA micro SDXC 64 GB card with a claim of 95MB/s and I'm using it with my Nikon D600.

I have used it one night and all is well. Last night I used it for night photography - without any lag in taking pictures and previews were appearing (as it should be). This morning I wanted to import the pictures into Lightroom - no pictures were found.

I double checked with Finder - it found a few but I have effectively lost approximately 75% of my shots from the previous night.

There were numbers skipped (where the pictures I actually took were supposed to be).

I have tried to use Wondershare Data Recovery to recover data from the SD card but nothing was found.

1. What happened?
2. Is this a micro SDXC issue? I returned to a 32GB card the day after
   with my camera and all is well.
3. Can I recover this lost data? (i.e. it went somewhere that I can't see)

Comment: As no-one else has picked up on this one... have you tested at least that the card is not a fake? I've used this app before for testing, no doubt Google has many more - Fight Flash Fraud app [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X)

Comment: @Tetsujin I have checked with F3 and ran the test. all is positive and it is not a fake.

Comment: Sorry, then I've no better idea other than the file recovery software of your choice.

Comment: If you are a tech-savvy guy, you could consider a data dump... but it involves some coding in python and some relatively cheap hardware purchases. (as a plus, you don't really risk card damage at all). If you haven't gotten it fixed that is. This is the site I found for general [info.](http://tech.tiefpunkt.com/2013/08/sd-card-recovery-using-an-arduino/)

Comment: A-DATA. Too late now. Next time, use a reliable brand: Sandisk, Kingston, Lexar (until recently). might be a few more.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to a friend of mine. The next day after a photo shoot, she went to transfer to her computer and most of the photos were just gone.

I don't have personal experience with Wondershare, but I was able to recover all of her missing photos using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). I've recovered images from SD cards with PhotoRec on multiple occasions over the last 10 years.

In general, **don't do any SD card testing until all efforts have been made to recover the photos first!** Some tests are destructive and sometimes if the SD card is on it's way out, you'll have limited time to extract what you need.

Make sure you are using a high quality SD card reader. I've generally found that a dedicated USB3-SD card adapter to be more reliable than the internal SD card readers on my laptops.

If you can't identify what caused the photos to disappear, assume you have a bad SD card even if it passes fake card tests. Just replace it with a another reputable card. Sometimes we just get a bad one and it's not worth the risk of your future photos to keep using one that's questionable. It may be worth replacing anything else that could be questionable and doesn't cost much. 
With my friends situation, I suspected her old USB-SD adapter as the cause of the corruption (unconfirmed but I had her throw it away and get a nice new one just in case).

Good luck!